# Проблема с решением игровой задачи

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, ооп, логика

У меня возникла проблема с реализацией алгоритма для игровой задачи.

**Задание такое:** Найти такие 12 натуральных чисел, которые не превышают 19, что бы их сума по всем направлениями, указаными стрелкой, были равны 38. Числа не должны повторятся.
[image: Задание]

Ячейки я решил рассматривать как двумерный массив **int** значений, если его чуть-чуть наклонить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сразу же его инициализировал, согласно условию.

```
int mass[5][6]={{3,17,18,-1,-1,-1},{0,0,1,0,-1,-1},{16,2,0,0,0,-1},{0,0,0,0,-1,-1},{10,0,0,-1,-1,-1}};
```

Проблему составил алгоритм перебора значений пустых ячеек, обозначенных **0**-ем. Что-то не могу ничего толкового придумать.

Comment: В вашем вопросе нет чёткого вопроса. Может вам граф взять для хранения данных.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш массив не даёт вам лёгких путей подбора. Я бы пошёл по другому пути - создал бы класс, который:

1. хранил бы в себе массив значений и координат. Можно использовать обычную декартовую, а можно - [гексагональную](https://habrahabr.ru/post/193668/), так будет проще строить векторы. С другой стороны, у вас всего-то 19 ячеек, так что векторы вы можете даже задать руками.
2. реализовывал методы, позволяющие получить вектор со значениями и его сумму.
3. реализовывал инструмент (в виде массива, или ещё как-то) с остаточным набором чисел.

Дальше - как в судоку. Перебираем векторы, в которых всего лишь одна пустая ячейка. Она заполняется автоматически, число вычеркивается из остаточного набора и помещается в соответствующую ячейку массива. Когда таких векторов не останется, при этом остаточный набор ненулевой, решается задача по подбору вариантов с перебором векторов. В принципе, конечная задача сводится к матричному анализу, но реализовать универсальный матричный анализ, боюсь, будет на порядок сложнее, чем простой перебор.

Comment: Сколько векторов должно быть и как они должны двигаться?

Comment: @Viksem Вектор здесь понимается, как понятие из линейной алгебры, а не из физики. Векторов столько, сколько всего  ваших направлений. Фактически, вектор = массив ячеек с известными и пустыми значениями. Может быть длиной 3, 4, 5 для вашей задачи. Двигаться они не должны, это вы передвигаетесь по ним :)